# Particle Morph Transition between two objects

Tags: modifiers, objects, particles, transforms, faces

Basically, I want to disassemble 1st Object to assemble into the 2nd Object via individual extruded faces or solid blocks like cell fracture that are manipulated like particles guided a path for its destination. A good example is the particle transformation in Transformers 4. Two other examples are from Starlord's Helmet animation in Guardians of the Galaxy and The New Power Rangers Movie Trailer when particles were assembling into Jasons suit at the end. I've investigated a few options but haven't found smooth particle transition. The Expolsion modifier was good for disassembling like the particles using volume but the transition to another object isn't smooth especially with Cubes as particles. The Add-On: Particle Morphing Tool showed the best promise:

https://vimeo.com/50176510

However, the download no longer exists and the developer isn't responding. So If there is any advise to accomplish this transition please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would keyed particle physics do? [Youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/lPCs4XbGth8)

Comment: The [animation nodes addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCghhlMOwRg) can be used to make individual polys fly around, I expect you could disassemble one object and assemble another using it.

Comment: Thanks Duane Dibbley, but unfortunately I've tried that effect already it works better when the particles are small and many. I need them to be larger cubes.

Comment: Sambler, I like the the Animation Nodes add-on. It looks very close to the idea I looking for for transitioning one object to another via particle effect. I'll look more into it try it out. Thank you.